# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Main"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, php-ziparchive

I am all stuck , Searching for a while and didn't get the answer , I am using third party library [ZipArchive](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive) for unzip the file.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Main", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NetworkManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Below is Error Log :

```
Ld /Users/ngi-raheelmateen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eQuiz-Sample-gxbnecbwpozhqweupuoifjuubzzx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/eQuiz-Sample.app/eQuiz-Sample normal x86_64
    cd /Users/ngi-raheelmateen/Documents/EQUIZ-IOS
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.4
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk -L/Users/ngi-raheelmateen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eQuiz-Sample-gxbnecbwpozhqweupuoifjuubzzx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/ngi-raheelmateen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eQuiz-Sample-gxbnecbwpozhqweupuoifjuubzzx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/ngi-raheelmateen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eQuiz-Sample-gxbnecbwpozhqweupuoifjuubzzx/Build/Intermediates/eQuiz-Sample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/eQuiz-Sample.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/eQuiz-Sample.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lAFNetworking -lAMScrollingNavbar -lDTModelStorage -lDTTableViewManager -lMMDrawerController -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework Foundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.4 -lz -lPods-eQuiz-Sample -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/ngi-raheelmateen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eQuiz-Sample-gxbnecbwpozhqweupuoifjuubzzx/Build/Intermediates/eQuiz-Sample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/eQuiz-Sample.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/eQuiz-Sample_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/ngi-raheelmateen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eQuiz-Sample-gxbnecbwpozhqweupuoifjuubzzx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/eQuiz-Sample.app/eQuiz-Sample
```

Any Helpfull answer is much appreiated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the requirements of the API,  may be you need some iOS frameworks to include.